# How to check that 1 element is a "true" in response

Tags: javascript

I'm blocking because I'm trying to loop to check if the checkboxes in my item ("this.current.response") are True
my code :

```
while (verif < this.current.response.length) {
    if (this.current.response[verif] == true) {
        ok = true;
    }
    verif++
}

if (ok == false) {
    error = true
}
```

in this.current.response :

```
1:{} 
2:{}
3:{}
```

these are checkbox questions (there are 3 here for example);
I am on the first question, when I click I go to the second;;
how to loop to check that there is a TRUE to validate and go to the next question

Thank you for your help

Comment: Paste more code please :)

Comment: there is no more code;
this code is for a checkbox;
and I would like to take it for a group of checkboxes, check for each element if there is an answer (checked = true / uncheck = false)  :)

Comment: ?? help please ??

Comment: post the HTML code instead of re-opening the same question

Comment: So, you're after something that checks whether at least one of the check boxes / radio buttons in a group are selected / checked?

Comment: Can you either post more details regarding what `this.current.response` contains or more surrounding code.

Comment: yes I put below: this.current.response = 1:{} ect..

Comment: in fact with each subsequent click (of my button) I go from 1: {} to 2: {}
when a reply is given and I click on my button I go from 1: {1: true2: false} (so that's good) to 2: { }

Comment: et avec mon code la bouche garde le vrai de 1: {1: vrai 2: faux} et que je tique ou non le 2: {} ça me fait suivre tout de même

Comment: #scagood @scagood

Comment: Est-ce que `this.current.response` un `object` ou un `array`?, par example, `buttons = [['repondre 1.1', 'repondre 1.2'], ['repondre 2.1', 'repondre 2.2'], ...]?
Et, je ne comprends 'la bouche garde le vrai'? 'the mouth guard is true'? (Sorry, for my butchery of French.)

Comment: sorry I had not put in English

Comment: this.current.responce = [1:{ }, 2:{ }........]

Comment: It's an array with objects;
and each object corresponds to a question from the checkbox;

Comment: I would like to check that in each object there is the value "true" (checked = true).
if there is no value true (I refer to an error) already written

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(var i=1 ;i<=this.current.response.length; i++){
    var result = this.current.response[i];
      while(verif < this.current.response.length){
        if(result[verif]==true){
          console.log(result)
          ok= true;console.log("ouououo");  
        }
        verif++;

      }
  }
      if(ok==false){
        error=true
      }
```

because with this code, I put to the real first item and each item takes into account the truth of the first question; I want to reset the value so that I can redo it for each question.
My question is this.current.response => 1: {} (first question) 2: {} (second question) ect ...